# How to catch error in jQuery's load() method

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling, load

I'm using jQuery's `.load()` method to retrieve some data when a user clicks on a button.

After the load successfully finishes, I show the result in a `<div>`.

The problem is, sometimes an error occurs in `load()` while retrieving the data.

How can I catch an error in `load()`?

Comment: This question is from 2009, so please note from [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/): _Prior to jQuery 3.0, the event handling suite also had a method named .load(). Older versions of jQuery determined which method to fire based on the set of arguments passed to it._

Answer (score 92):

[load() documentation.](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load)

Just a little background on how a load error happens...

```
$("body").load("/someotherpath/feedsx.pxhp", {limit: 25}, 
    function (responseText, textStatus, req) {
        if (textStatus == "error") {
          return "oh noes!!!!";
        }
});
```

Edit: Added a path other than the root path as requested by comments.

Comment: thanks altCongnito.it is work!
btw,can i ask another related question?
another problem is file path! I use asp.net.
i write load() code in Master page. parameter Url is like feedsx.aspx.
it is work when content pages are under root folder.but if content pages are under other subfolder not work. help

Comment: thanks for the link to the jquery docs.  I didn't know they even existed!

Comment: Thanks - load failures are mostly due to a problem when loading the target page.

Answer (score 13):

Besides passing a callback to the load() function as Ólafur Waage suggests, you can also register "global" error handlers (global as in global for all ajax calls on the page).

There are at least two ways to register global Ajax error handlers :

Register just the error handler with [`ajaxError()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/ajaxError#callback):

```
$.ajaxError(function(event, request, settings) {
      alert("Oops!!");
});
```

Or, use [`ajaxSetup()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajaxSetup#options) to set up an error handler and other properties at the same time:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 5000,
    error: function(event, request, settings){
        alert("Oops!");
    }
});
```

Comment: i'm using jquery 3.5, and it has no `$.ajaxError` function, although it's still in documentation: https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Comment: As of jQuery 1.9, it's `$(document).ajaxError` instead of just `$.ajaxError`

Answer (score 7):

load() offers a callback.

> Callback.
> The function called when the ajax request is complete (not necessarily success).

This is how its done IIRC. (haven't tested it)

```
$("#feeds").load("feeds.php", {limit: 25}, 
    function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        // XMLHttpRequest.responseText has the error info you want.
        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
});
```

Comment: The first argument of the function IS responseText. No need to use XMLHttpRequest.responseText...

Answer (score 0):

Electric toolbox has an article called ["Loading content with jQuery AJAX and dealing with failures"](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/load-content-jquery-ajax-dealing-with-failures/) that appears to answer your question.

Apparently the callback function that you specify gets passed the response, status, and XmlHttpRequest object, allowing you to determine the status of your ajax request and handle the condition accordingly.