# jQuery .load() error state?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to get this solution to work for me.

[How to catch error in jQuery's load() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753300/how-to-catch-error-in-jquerys-load-method)

here's the code I'm trying.

```
$("#a").load("load.html", function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        if (textStatus == "error") { alert("fail"); }
        else { alert("success"); }
});
```

when load.html exists, it works fine, but when it doesn't nothing happens. Which makes sense since it shouldn't get to the callback if it fails.

Can someone point out where I am going wrong? I'm trying to get it to throw out an error when the URL doesn't exist.

I'm trying to work with jQuery 1.3.2 if that affects anything.

**Update**
The problem seems to be because I'm working locally and not on a server. Uploaded my files online and it seems to be working fine, is there parts of jQuery which require a server to function?

**Update**
Did some more testing and using .load() with the error callback doesn't work offline, yet .ajax() does. Baffled at why, but there we go.

Comment: May be request from server has status "OK" and empty body. In this case you will not get any errors. Because you got empty and correct page. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/  but in this case you should add code that adds result into your element

Comment: jQuery 1.3.2 is really old, as things like that go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'load.html',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
         //handle data object containing the html
         $('#a').html(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, error){
        //generic error callback, you'll end up here when your file doesnt exist
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it here :

```html
<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#div1").load("demo_tes.txt", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
                if(statusTxt === "success")
                    alert("External content loaded successfully!");
                if(statusTxt === "error")
                    alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```