# On link click load html page in container

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

Jquery novice here with a quick question. I have two empty containers in the html:
    `<aside></aside>`
    `<section></section>`

Then I load content into it:

```
$('aside').load('timeline.html #dates');
$('section').load('timeline.html #intro');
```

`#dates` contains links that, when clicked on, should replace and load its url content into `<section>` without reloading the whole page. I tried making a click handler but it's not working (on click still leaves current page and goes to url):

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $('section').empty().load(url);  
});
```

I even tried this variation to no avail:

```
$('aside a').on('click', function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $('section').empty().load(url);
    return false;
});
```

I could use iframes, but I don't want to since I'm learning about .load(). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Karaxuna, Neuro, Sarath and others, here's the code that I got working. .load() retains CSS from the loaded page which caused conflicts, so on link click I just hid section and loaded the new page in an iframe instead (no css conflicts). And to make sure I'm only targeting certain elements I'm using the > selector so as not to target duplicate tags when .load() is in the picture.

```
<aside>
</aside>

<section>
</section>
<iframe class="no-display">
</iframe>   

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('aside').load('timeline.html #dates');
    $('body > section').load('timeline.html #intro');
    $(document).on('click', 'aside a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body > section').hide();
        $('iframe').removeClass('no-display');
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('iframe').attr('src', (url));
    });
 });    
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use `ajax` rather than `load`?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/yHVMA/

```
$('aside a').on('click', function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'jsonp', //for x-domain
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("section").html(data);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert("bugger!\r\n" + data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I guess I prefer `ajax` because of the `success` and `error` events

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753300/how-to-catch-error-in-jquerys-load-method

Comment: Works fine in jsfiddle but it's still not loading in `<section>`. It's live now in my project if you want to see: [link](http://www.nevblog.com/nevblog-timeline/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'aside a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    $('section').empty().load(url);
});
```

In your case event may not be attached to anchor if the anchor is loaded dynamically

Comment: Hey Karaxuna, I tried this earlier but it causes the page to freeze. Why does it do that (when I put `'click', 'aside a'`)?

Comment: Here's a live example: [link](http://www.nevblog.com/nevblog-timeline/index2.html)

Comment: @matenji because you have 242 `section` tags on page :)) and `$('section').empty().load(url);` will of course cause it. `$('section')` selects all 242 tags

Comment: Thank you! I did deeper css targeting which helped.

Answer (score 1):

You're registering the `click()` handlers before the content is loaded. You'll have to do this after the content is loaded, from the `complete` handler of `load()`:

```
function click_handler() {
    $(this).load($(this).attr("href"), {}, add_handlers)
    return false;
}

function add_handlers() {
    $(this).find('a').click(click_handler)
}

$('#box').load('/whatever/', {}, add_handlers)
```

Note how `add_handlers()` is run everytime after loading new content. See [an example that reloads the same link when you click on it](http://jsfiddle.net/ayu45/3/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the id for the section where you want the page to load  and load into that section tag.Since there are a lot of section in your page

```
<section id="sec"></section>
```

then the code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
         var url = $(this).attr("href");
       $('#sec').empty().load(url);  
    });
    });
```